# Typescript - Setting the type for a null property, when defining the initial state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

After defining the initial state for the reducers in Redux, I want to get the type for the initial state so it gets automatically updated if I add any properties to the state.

Here is my definition of the initial state

```js
let initialState = {
  food: {
    data: null,
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null
  }
}
```

Then I extract the type definitions from this state

```js
export type StoreState = typeof initialState;
```

The `food.data` property should be of the type `Food`, which is defined as follows:

```js
export interface Food {
  fdcId: number
  description: string
  nutrients: Array<Nutrient>
}

export interface Nutrient {
  name: string
  unitName: string
  amount: number
}
```

By default `food.data` gets defined as the type `never` when assigning it `null` in the initial state. That way when I want to access the property `nutrients` of it I get an error saying `Property 'nutrients' does not exist on type 'never'`.

Defining `food.data` with `null as Food` won't work because that also give errors.

If I define `food.data` with `{} as Food`, then I won't be able to set it to `null` in the reducer.

So my question then is, how can I define the property `food.data` such that when I get the `typeof` for the initial state it knows that `food.data` is of the type `Food` and such that `food.data` still can be `null`?

Comment: try using `foods: Food[] = {} as Food[]` instead. Right now you're declaring the type to be an array of no type.

Comment: I don't know anything about react and redux, but it seems you're doing things backwards. Instead of defining a value (the initial state), and using it to define the type, you should define a type, and define an initial state value that has that type.

Comment: @fredrik Sorry for the misleading, but it was the `food.data` property that I define to `null` that was causing the trouble and not the Food array

Comment: Well, your `initialState` variable has no type and I can't see a definition for data anywhere. So how would you expect it to work?

Comment: @JBNizet Doing it this way makes it easier to add properties to the initial state. Otherwise I would have to add the properties to both the type definitions and to the initial state

Comment: And that's the proper thing to do. You define the contract (the type) first, and then the compiler checks that the variables fulfill the contract.

Comment: @fredrik The definition of `data` is in the `food` object which is inside the `initialState`. It is defined as null for the start

Comment: @martin36 you're trying to make the compiler infer the type of data as Food from a value which is `null`. There is no way for the compiler to do that. Could you tell what I would like the type of foo to be in this piece of code? `const foo = null;`

Comment: In your question I can see no definition of data in the `Food` interface. Again, `initialState` has no type (or rather it has an anonymous type)...

Comment: @JBNizet We can use the statement `as` in Typescript to tell the compiler that a property is of a certain type. For example `[] as Food[]`, then the compiler knows that the array is an array of `Food` items. I was looking for somthing similar but when the property is initialized as null

Comment: `null as Food` is valid. If you use strict null checks, use `null as Food | null`. But still, it would be much cleaner to properly define a type for the state.

Answer (score 3):

By defining the data as `null` or `Food`, I got it to work

```js
let initialState = {
  food: {
    data: null as (null | Food),
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null
  },
}
```